# Log RAW request from HttpClient?

Tags: c#, request, postman, raw

I have generated a .NET Core 6 C# httpClient with NSwagStudio from a json file that is used in my winform application. To test this client Im using mock service in Postman.

Postman reacts with "No matching requests" so I need to add a request example. The problem is that I don't know how it looks like? So how can i log the request that then can be added to postman?

I have looked at the [HTTP logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but it seems like it do not log RAW json files and it's mainly for ASP.NET Core.

So how can I get a proper request doc to add in postman?

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to capture the request? (Or Wireshark to be even lower level.) That way you know exactly what's on the wire, with no interpretation.

Comment: Tried it but my laptop will not let wireshark log any traffic.